# aes128 encryption in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

**NODE.JS CODE (DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED)**

```
var input = '200904281000001|DOM|IND|INR|10|orderno_unique1|others|http://localhost/sample/Success.php|http://localhost/sample/failure.php|TOML';

var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes128', "qcAHa6tt8s0l5NN7UWPVAQ==");

var actual = cipher.update(input_string, "utf8", "base64");
    actual += cipher.final("base64"); 
   console.log(actual);
```

**Actual Output**

> bIK4D0hv2jcKP3eikoaM7ddqRee+RrT2FDOZA+c2sldyrqP+NrmgYOEXklUrSBQiU7w7e90nzFl/mpidy/Q8FD692bFLnESiNqGEQ7er44BXxFtNo6AKvpuohz31zm9JupJXL3jhOC+47mvDHokR4b9euDzPFitTJQW55JuSyvJphOKdiXjH+lGKxXKWsODq

**Expected Output**

> ncJ+HX6zIdrUfEedi7YC82QOUARkySblivzysFbMqaYEMPj7UfMlE4SEkDcjg+D9dE5StGJgebSOkL7UuR6fXwodcgL0CSRds0Y+hX27gKUZK45b7Tc0EjXhepwHJ/olSdWUCkwRcZcv+wxtYzOH7+KKijJabJkU1/SF1ugExzcnqfV2wOZ9q79a4y/g3cb5

**PHP CODE (WORKS AS EXPECTED)**

Comment: I think you're missing the PHP code.

Comment: You forgot to add the PHP code, which despite you saying that it works, still might not be optimal or might be the indirect source of the problems.

Comment: You also didn't post that you're Base64-decoding the password before feeding it to `createCipher`.